# Django: html submit form that is unique for each element in a list

Tags: python, django, for-loop, model

In a template of my project, I am using a `for` loop to iterate over each object in a model. Each object needs a button next to it that will delete THAT object from the model. So each button needs to be linked to a specific object, and clicking that button will tell views.py which object has been licked and to delete that object.

models.py:

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
```

template.html:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {{object.name}}<br>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        <button type="submit">Select</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def delete(request):
    objects = Obj.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the specific object that the form was submitted for
        # Remove the object from the model (which removes it from the html list as well)
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'objects', objects})
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a form? You could simply create a link for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the id of your object alongside your request.
So you add the object id in your form:

```
{% for object in objects %}
    {{object.name}}<br>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}  {# Don't forget this one ! #}

        <button type="submit" name="object-id" value="{{ object.pk }}">Select</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

You then delete the object from your view:

```py
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseNotAllowed


def delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            obj = Obj.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('object-id'))
        except Object.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404()

        obj.delete()

        return reverse('...')

    return HttpResponseNotAllowed()
```

Comment: This is true. I wanted to highlight input validation since new users often forget about it.